# PHP Making class constructor variables global between classes

Tags: php, class, variables

I did some searching and found examples of defining global variables for a class in its constructor, but my question is, how can I make a class constructor variable global between multiple classes on the same php?

For Example:

```
$the_variable = new first_class();

class first_class {
    function first() {
        //does something
    }
}

class second_class {
    function second() {
        global $the_variable;
        $the_variable->first(); 
        //does something
    }
}

class third_class {
    function third() {
        global $the_variable;
        $the_variable->first(); 
        //does something
    }
}

class fourth_class {
    function fourth() {
        global $the_variable;
        $the_variable->first(); 
    }
}
```

How can I make the_variable accessible without having to write global in every single function in the classes?

Comment: That is a **terrible** idea and **horrible** programming practice. Don't do it. Learn about Dependancy Injection.

Comment: So you're saying I should be using the constructor in the class?

Comment: I took a look at some examples and explanations, I understand now thanks.